# What is the avantage of having memory mapped I/O?

Tags: computer-architecture, memory-management

I can't make out what is the avantage of it comparing with the port designed I/O

Is it faster? Is it more reliable? Is it cheaper?

Comment: This is asked in [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-memory-mapped-I-O-and-direct-or-port-I-O).

Answer (score 4):

There are many advantages to memory mapped I/O

1. Access: Memory mapped devices use the same instructions/addressing modes as regular memory. These map well into high level languages allowing device drivers to manipulate devices without the need to drop down into assembly language to use special I/O instructions.
2. Security: As memory addressed devices, memory management hardware can be used to control access to those devices. Generally, I/O instructions are "wide open" in privileged modes allowing a driver to access any I/O mapped device, even those that it should not.
3. Flexibility: Almost without exception, the processor instructions available for memory are more varied and versatile than those for I/O mapped. With memory, load/store instructions are supplemented with various monodic (inc/dec/etc) and dyadic (add/sub/etc) operators. Special I/O mode instructions are generally limited to load/store. This typically gives the compiler a better shot at creating better code (ignoring the whole RISC/CISC debate for now).

Support for special I/O mapping is generally a legacy issue. The x86 for example is (on some level) compatible all the way back to the 8008.

Very old processors often included I/O mapped device support because the memory address space was so small (often 65,536 bytes or less) that I/O addressing provided a way to preserve memory address space for actual memory.

Modern processors have larger (4G or larger) address spaces so that this is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you rely on port io you drive up the pin count. Memory mapping provides a more flexible method in the design. They're really two very different things with different intentions. Ports are generally speaking extensions of the processor that map to specific functions. A memory map is a extension that allows access. It's more abstract. At least until you put something into the map. :)